# Breaking WPF views into components and maintaining databinding

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am working on a standard data-entry app in WPF/MVVM. I have a file called LabSetupView.xaml and in it I have three Controls:

1. a ComboBox for displaying available Labs
2. a ComboBox for displaying Technicians
3. ListView for Tests

These controls are meant to work together - when a user selects a Technician, only the Tests for that TechnicianId are displayed. This is done via the navigation property on Technician to Tests.

I am considering moving these Controls into their own .xaml file each as a `<UserControl>` and then nesting them inside the `<Window>` because the DataContext for LabSetupView.xaml can only be set once. So, I thought if I componentize the controls, I could have ViewModels for each of them (i.e. LabView.xaml/LabViewModel.xaml etc...) and each inheriting from a single ViewModelBase that implements the necessary `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

My question is: Is it a common or normal practice to have a base-plate .xaml file that itself doesnt have a data context but rather contains separate UserControls, each of which with their own datacontext?

I am asking this because I am concerned that if I attempt something like this, then the data-binding and INotifyProperChanged wont work together because these Views are componentized. In other words, my Use Case above (getting Tests for a Techncian) won't bind or update property.

Comment: You are on the right track, but I would still have a base ViewModel used as a DataContext for the window. That MainViewModel would include properties for each of your other ViewModels (or, probably more accurately, ObservableCollections of your other ViewModels).  Adding this as a comment because I don't really have time to set up a full answer with an example, but wanted to get you on the right path.

Comment: Agreed @WonkotheSane, I've written up this type approach in the answer below.

Comment: @WonkotheSane So, for example, if TechnicianViewModel.xaml inherits from ViewModelBase, as I suggested, you are saying that same ViewModelBase should be the datacontext for the window? Or are you saying that the LabSetupView.xaml should have its own LabSetupViewModel.xaml (which inherits from ViewModelBase as well), and its THIS viewmodel that has the ObservableCollections of the other UserControl ViewModels? Thanks for the reponse, by the way.

Comment: ViewModelBase will probably be an abstract class that all of your ViewModel classes inherit from.  You will then have a main view model that inherits from that, and has the properties I mentioned (see the answer from @BrianS below).  One more note - your UserControls will be Views, based on separate ViewModel classes - do not make the mistake of using the code-behind of the UserControl a "ViewModel".

Comment: @WonkotheSane Oh, I certainly would not make that mistake! I have been practicing WPF with the Patterns In Action Framework from doFactory to learn how to implement patterns within MVVM and EF. Sadly, what brought me to this question is that they only have single view that contains a single ListBox of Customers, and not multiple kinds of Business Domain Objects that need to be displayed in a single view. Hence my question. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly have your main view (base-plate .xaml file, as you describe it above) not have a `DataContext` and then assign the `DataContext` on specific child controls, whether they're `UserControls` or otherwise.

However, from what you describe, you may want to consider using Composition with your ViewModels.  In this scenario, you'd have a MainViewModel which has properties representing the ChildViewModel (Technician & Test).  These child ViewModels could communicate through the MainViewModel or not, depending on how you want to compose things.  Then, the `DataContext` of the main view would be the MainViewModel, and the `UserControls` would just `DataBind` to the properties of that view model.

It might look something like this:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public TechnicianViewModel Technician { get { return _technician; } }
    public TestViewModel Test { get { return _test; } }
    ...
}
```

And an abbreviated example of the XAML would look like this (assuming MainViewModel has been set as the DataContext for the Window):

```
<Window x:Class="MainView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

      <StackPanel>
           <local:TechnicianView DataContext="{Binding Technician}"/>
           <local:TestView DataContext="{Binding Test}"/>
      </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

This is how I've addressed the type of scenario you have above and it works well.  It works very well when you can use IoC/DI to inject the child view models through an IoC container.

**EDITED**

Based on your comment/question below, some additional detail.  You ask how to establish the relationship between a selected technician and the tests available to that technician.  One way to handle this would be to have the TestsViewModel be a child of the TechnicanViewModel.  So, for example, you could have the following:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<TechnicianViewModel> AvailableTechnicians { get { return _technicians; } }
    public TechnicianViewModel SelectedTechnician 
    { 
        get { return _selected; } 
        set 
        { 
            _selected = value; 
            RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTechnician");
        } 
    }
    ...
}

public class TechnicianViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<TestViewModel> Tests { get { return _tests; } }
}
```

And then in your XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
     <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTechnicians}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTechnician, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
     <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTechnician.Tests}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This will synchronize the Tests `ListBox` with the selected technician in the Technicians `ListBox`.  This is just an example (written in a text editor, not VS if I've got any mistakes), but one way to handle the kind of relationship you're discussing.

Comment: So if the ListBox of Tests in Test.xaml has an ItemSource that is bound to the CurrentTechnician Property in the TechnicianViewModel does the relationship still work when CurrentTechnician is changed (when I select another technician)? I still trying to wrap my head around this more distributed relationship. Sorry to seem thick :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a method for establishing the relationship you describe.

Comment: Is the xaml you provided in your edit still within MainView or is it on the TechnicianView.xaml?

Comment: It would be within MainView.  I switched it to `ListBoxes`, but it could still be your custom `UserControls` if you wanted (if they don't have an `ItemsSource` property, you can set it to the `DataContext` and then within the `UserControl` set the `ItemsSource` on the `ListBox`).  But if your `UserControls` are simply wrapping the `ListBox`, they may not be necessary.

Comment: You've certainly gone above and beyond for a measly few points. I'll be sure to upvote once I get the rep. If you dont mind though, why wouldn't you simply set the bindings up in the TechnicianView?

Comment: Glad to help.  You certainly could setup the bindings differently, in the TechnicianView, for example, but without seeing and knowing more about how your views are composed, it is hard to say what might be best.  The xaml I've provided is really just an example of how it could be done - it is certainly not the only way, and depending on your specific scenario, it may not be the best.  I just wanted to demonstrate one scenario so that you can take it from there to figure out what's best for your case.  Good luck!

Comment: Indeed I am taking the ball and running with it as I type this. I have already begun to redefine my Views. Thanks again, Brian.

Comment: Brian, re-opening this question so-to-speak how would I take the ListBox in your Edit (the one that is bound to SelectedTechnician.Tests) and break out the Tests properties as columns like one might do by by making the ListBox a ListView and adding GridView to the ListView.View property?

Comment: @IsaiahNelson, [Here is a tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/742/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1) on using the `ListView` that seems pretty straightforward.  It is really easy, and similar to the `ListBox` in that each row binds to an item in the list.  The main difference is that you setup each column to bind to a property on the item.